# Java Question .What is the problem in my code?

Tags: java

Sometimes, the normal if-else isn't enough. In such cases, we have what we call ladder if and else conditions.  So here we'll learn to use them.

Given a positive integer N. Your task is to check if it divisible as given below:

1. If it is divisible by 2, print "Two".
2. If it is divisible by 3, print "Three".
3. If it is divisible by 11, print "Eleven".
4. If not follow above three rules, print "-1".

Note: If N is divisible by more than one of the above given numbers, print the one which is largest.

Input Format:
First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each testcases, there will be a single line containing N.

Output Format:
For each testcase, check divisibility and print statements accordingly as given in above steps (without quotes).

Your Task:
Your task is to complete the function to check divisibility as required.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 10
1 <= N <= 106
```

Example:

Input:

```
2
3
11
```

Output:

```
Three
Eleven
```

** For More Input/Output Examples Use 'Expected Output' option **

```
class Geeks {
     static void isDivisibleByPrime (int n) 
     {
             //Your code here
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       int a[]=new int[n];
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           a[i]=sc.nextInt();
           if(a[i]%2==0)
           System.out.println("Two");
           else if(a[i]%3==0)
           System.out.println("Three");
           else if(a[i]%11==0)
           System.out.println("Eleven");
           else
           System.out.println("-1");
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn’t the parameter `n` supposed to be the number you’re checking?

Comment: but then there are 2 inputs according to the question .Can you plzz explain in detail ??

Comment: My interpretation was that the method you’re expected to fill in (`isDivisibleByPrime`) is called once per input value

Comment: That means .We have to check that n is divisible by 2,3 or 11 right ???? but in that case multiple test case is getting failed

Comment: Stack Overflow question: What is wrong with your title?

Answer (score 0):

First use braces around every block of code. it is easier to reading for everyone.

Second the point in your spec was to print the largest value if divisible, so you
should start with checking if it divides by 11 first, then 3 and then 2.

Right code is here:

```
    static void isDivisibleByPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 11 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Eleven");
    } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Three");
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Two");
    } else {
    System.out.println("-1");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

First things first - **always** use braces around **every** block of code - especially a beginner to the language. It will make your life easier, and anyone reading your code.

Second, the point in your spec was to print the largest value if divisible, so you should start with checking if it divides by 11 first, then 3 and then 2.

And lastly, I would get all the input first, and not in the `isDivisibleByPrime` method, and just call that method for each input.

So just leave your `isDivisibleByPrime` as

```
static void isDivisibleByPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 11 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Eleven");
    } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Three");
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Two");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-1");
    }
}
```

And call it elsewhere with the values

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of test cases:");
int numOfTestCases = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfTestCases; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter value to check:");
    int valueToCheck = sc.nextInt();
    isDivisibleByPrime(valueToCheck);
}
```

Obviously there's no error handling or whatnot, but as you're likely new to this, I'm sure it's not a requirement.

Here's an **[online](https://ideone.com/4qNJIZ)** example.